# 5x3 Half Round Problem

Tags: building

How can I hide on top of this with tile pieces?

[image: Half Round 5x3]

To make it like this:

[image]

Edit:
Thank @jncraton for the solution

Before answering I made it like this:

[image]

But now it looks way better and it will be more stable:

[image]

Comment: If the two small 1x1 quarter round tiles need to have clutch (meaning when you turn the build upside down, they won’t fall out), I am afraid the answer is “You cannot”.

Comment: Okay, thank you, but i was sure someone achieved something like this before.

Comment: How much of the volume do you have available for supporting the two quarter round tiles ? Just the volume directly underneath the tiles ? Or more ? How much more ?

Comment: Would two [Cylinder Half 1 x 2 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=68013) fit eg. ? (edit: I see @jncraton had the same idea)

Comment: @UranMaster Welcome to Bricks.SE and thanks for the clear pictures of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are able to use up some additional space inside the build, you should be able to use [68013 Brick Round, Half 1 x 2](https://rebrickable.com/parts/68013/brick-round-half-1-x-2/)  (one under each tile) to support the corners:

[image]